# How to generate dynamic font awesome icon in php for loop

Tags: php, font-awesome

I want to generate all current available font awesome icons dynamically in my php code, so user can select it.  Do I need to hardcode all icons in an array or database? or is there any shortcut light weight way to do this? for example;

```
<?php
foreach($fonticons as $icon){ // $fonticons is an abstract array, It have nothing
    echo '<i class="fa '.$icon.'"></i>';
}
?>
```

so I should get;

```
<i class="fa fa-adjust"></i>
<i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
<i class="fa fa-archive"></i>
<i class="fa fa-area-chart"></i>
<i class="fa fa-arrows"></i>
<i class="fa fa-hand"></i>....
```

is it possible?

I came to know that,

> every font awesome icon has a unique unicode.

for example `fa-adjust` unicode is `F042`. you can see it in console css as ****. So what if set counter starts to `F042` and loop and increment it in hex. and display this in html?

I can just copy paste this [array](http://bavotasan.com/2014/php-array-for-font-awesome-4-1-0/) and start using it. But I want it dynamic.

Comment: what do you have in `$fonticons` ?

Comment: nothing, just dummy.

Comment: Create a new array in your variable `$fonticons` and place all these icon-classes/names in it.

Comment: Since the names of the icons are nothing that can somehow be computed or predicted you have to use some form of catalog. So either you find some list on the project site or you have to create one yourself.

Comment: I got you all. see my updated question.

Comment: `hexadecimalcode` should be `unicode` :)

Comment: @C0dekid Are you sure? if yes, than edit again. i'll approve.

Comment: @MujahedAKAS yes, that's why I edited your post haha. Read the difference here if you want to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Problem solved, No need to create array. I've got free plugin [Font Awesome Icon Picker](http://mjolnic.com/fontawesome-iconpicker/) which takes care of all font awesome icons list and GUI and it gives a textbox with value in it so when form submits, we gets the value in post.

Answer (score 2):

Since only the name of the icon is different so stored all the name of the icons into some array and show like this ..

```
$icons = array('0' =>'adjust' ,'1'=>'anchor' );

foreach ($icons as $key => $res) {
    echo  '<i class="fa-'.$res.'"></i>';

}
```

Comment: I think the numbers are useless haha, the array can be shorter, but this is also a good solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

Since your array looks something like this:

```
$font_awesome_icons_array = array( ‘fa-glass’ => ‘\f000’, ‘fa-music’ => ‘\f001’, ‘fa-search’ => ‘\f002’, ....
```

You can do this in a foreach loop.

```
forech($font_awesome_icons_array as $key=>$value){
 echo '<i class="fa '.$key.'"></i>';
}
```

The out put would look like:

```
<i class="fa fa-glass"></i>
<i class="fa fa-music"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a yaml parser and process the icons.yml file provided by font awesome git repository:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

$yaml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('FONT_AWESOME_PATH/src/icons.yml'));
$icons = $yaml['icons'];

foreach($icons as $icon) {
    if(empty($icon['unicode'])) {
        continue;
    }
    echo '<i class="fa fa-'.$icon['id'].'"></i>';
}
```